# Is there a way to make sure there will always be maximum 2 rows in the list?

Tags: html, css

I have a dynamic list. Is there any way to make sure that there will always be maximum 2 rows in the list (if there are too many items in the list, the remaining ones should disappear)? Is it possible?

```css
ul{
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li{
padding: 10px;
border: solid green 1px;
list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> list item 1</li>
  <li> list item 2</li>
  <li> list item 3</li>
  <li> list item 4</li>
  <li> list item 5</li>
  <li> list item 6</li>
  <li> list item 7</li>
  <li> list item 8</li>
  <li> list item 9</li>
  <li> list item 10</li>
  <li> list item 11</li>
  <li> list item 12</li>
  <li> list item 13</li>
  <li> list item 14</li>
  <li> list item 15</li>
  <li> list item 16</li>
  <li> list item 17</li>
  <li> list item 18</li>
  <li> list item 19</li>
  <li> list item 20</li>
  <li> list item 21</li>
  <li> list item 22</li>
  <li> list item 23</li>
  <li> list item 24</li>
  <li> list item 25</li>
  <li> list item 26</li>
  <li> list item 27</li>
  <li> list item 28</li>
  <li> list item 29</li>
  <li> list item 30</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If your `li` items have fixed height, you could set `max-height` for `ul` for two rows and hide the rest with `overflow: hidden`

Comment: I don't think you've explained what constitutes as a *"row"*. Do you mean an item as in `<li>`? Or do you mean multiple `<li>` in one row? If the latter, you should say so with specifics ex. 15 `<li>` in each row.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve something like that with a trick when using a CSS grid:

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  column-gap: 2px; /* you cannot use grid-gap! */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden; /* hide grid items that overflow */
}

li {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid green 1px;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> list item </li>
  <li> list item </li>
  <li> list item </li>
  <li> list item </li>
  <li> list item </li>
  <li> list item </li>
  <li> list item </li>
  <li> list item </li>
  <li> list item </li>
  <li> list item </li>
  <li> list item </li>
  <li> list item </li>
  <li> list item </li>
  <li> list item </li>
  <li> list item </li>
  <li> list item </li>
  <li> list item </li>
  <li> list item </li>
  <li> list item </li>
  <li> list item </li>
  <li> list item </li>
  <li> list item </li>
  <li> list item </li>
  <li> list item </li>
  <li> list item </li>
  <li> list item </li>
  <li> list item </li>
  <li> list item </li>
  <li> list item </li>
  <li> list item </li>
</ul>
```

After defining `grid-template-rows` for the first two rows you can use `grid-auto-rows` to set the height of all following rows to 0 which you can hide by using `overflow-y: hidden;`, ultimately.

Unfortunately, it will bug out when you use `grid-gap` to ensure spacing between elements, so you can compensate it by using `column-gap` with `margin-bottom` on the children.

Answer (score 0):

```css
li:nth-child(1n+2) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> list item 1</li>
  <li> list item 2</li>
  <li> list item 3</li>
  <li> list item 4</li>
  <li> list item 5</li>
  <li> list item 6</li>
  <li> list item 7</li>
  <li> list item 8</li>
  <li> list item 9</li>
  <li> list item 10</li>
  <li> list item 11</li>
  <li> list item 12</li>
  <li> list item 13</li>
  <li> list item 14</li>
  <li> list item 15</li>
  <li> list item 16</li>
  <li> list item 17</li>
  <li> list item 18</li>
  <li> list item 19</li>
  <li> list item 20</li>
  <li> list item 21</li>
  <li> list item 22</li>
  <li> list item 23</li>
  <li> list item 24</li>
  <li> list item 25</li>
  <li> list item 26</li>
  <li> list item 27</li>
  <li> list item 28</li>
  <li> list item 29</li>
  <li> list item 30</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This will remove all but the first three list items, not those that appear after the 3rd row.

Answer (score 0):

One method would be set `li` items to static height, then `ul` height can be calculated to limit only 2 rows, hiding the rest:

```css
ul{
--li-height: 3em;
--li-padding: 10px;
--li-border: 1px;
font-size: 0.5em;

display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;

max-height: calc((var(--li-height) + ((var(--li-padding) + var(--li-border)) * 2)) * 2);
overflow: hidden;
}

li{
padding: var(--li-padding);
border: solid green var(--li-border);
list-style: none;
height: var(--li-height);
}

.resize
{
  resize: horizontal;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>resize container</div>
<ul class="resize">
<li> list item 1</li>
<li> list item 2</li>
<li> list item 3</li>
<li> list item 4</li>
<li> list item 5</li>
<li> list item 6</li>
<li> list item 7</li>
<li> list item 8</li>
<li> list item 9</li>
<li> list item 10</li>
<li> list item 11</li>
<li> list item 12</li>
<li> list item 13</li>
<li> list item 14</li>
<li> list item 15</li>
<li> list item 16</li>
<li> list item 17</li>
<li> list item 18</li>
<li> list item 19</li>
<li> list item 20</li>
<li> list item 21</li>
<li> list item 22</li>
<li> list item 23</li>
<li> list item 24</li>
<li> list item 25</li>
<li> list item 26</li>
<li> list item 27</li>
<li> list item 28</li>
<li> list item 29</li>
<li> list item 30</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

The issue here is that your `<ul>` container has no explicit width set. Without it, it will try to fit as many child items as possible. Decide how wide you want your container to be to see how many child elements can fit on each row, and then `display: none` those that would start a third row.

In the code below, I've set the container to be 500px wide, which fits 5 of your child list items per row (at an explicit 75px each). The selector `li:nth-child(1n+11)` will remove the 11th element onwards.

```css
ul{
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
width: 500px;
}

li{
padding: 10px;
border: solid green 1px;
list-style: none;
width: 75px
}

li:nth-child(1n+11)
{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li> list item 1</li>
<li> list item 2</li>
<li> list item 3</li>
<li> list item 4</li>
<li> list item 5</li>
<li> list item 6</li>
<li> list item 7</li>
<li> list item 8</li>
<li> list item 9</li>
<li> list item 10</li>
<li> list item 11</li>
<li> list item 12</li>
<li> list item 13</li>
<li> list item 14</li>
<li> list item 15</li>
<li> list item 16</li>
<li> list item 17</li>
<li> list item 18</li>
<li> list item 19</li>
<li> list item 20</li>
<li> list item 21</li>
<li> list item 22</li>
<li> list item 23</li>
<li> list item 24</li>
<li> list item 25</li>
<li> list item 26</li>
<li> list item 27</li>
<li> list item 28</li>
<li> list item 29</li>
<li> list item 30</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your answer did not solve the problem, nor is mine a copy of yours. Run the snippet with your solution in place -- are the child elements starting after the second row removed?